# How to build the App (root component) in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I try to do the server-side rendering for App created by create-react-app (cra). What I want now is using all the default configs of cra to build the App (root) component, so in server I can easily render this component.

The problem is cra has entry point is index.js, I still want this entry point to build my SPA, but I also want to add another entry point to build the App component because I want this Component can be able to be rendered in server without complicated configs.

Is there any suggestions? If I can't, is there any way for me to render a Component in server with the same webpack and babel configs in cra?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at these kinds of links? Where are you stuck exactly? (1) https://github.com/dzianisbohush/cra-with-ssr, (2) https://zhirzh.medium.com/making-cra-apps-work-with-ssr-part-1-1e23d6b1603d

Comment: @Domi Thanks you for your link. Actually, I render my App in server successfully. But I can not use some of tools that cra support for example: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/ or CSS modules: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet. I'm not good at webpack or babel so I wonder if I can use the config of cra to build server code.